Laravel Eloquent Query Optimization for Pivot Table
I have asked this but this doesn't seems to me the efficient way of querying and even the cost is much more per query or search.
function is_voted($model) {
  return $model->voters->find(auth()->id());
}

function is_voted_up_or_down($model) {
  $is_up = $model->voters()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('type', 'up')->exists();
  $is_down = $model->voters()->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('type', 'down')->exists();
  if($is_up) { //$is_up has a boolean value true or false
    return "up";
  } elseif($is_down) { //$is_down has a boolean value true or false
    return "down";
  } else {
    return "not voted yet";
  }
}

